# How to show number of users currently online - 500,000 users?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Let's say I have a site with 100 million members and between around 500,000 users are logged in at any one time. Site uses Linux/Apache/PHP/MySQL. I would like to display a badge on the homepage showing the total number of users online - updated every minute. When visitors click on it, it should show a list of which users are online.

I considered an AJAX script that calls a PHP/MySQL file every 60 second and that updates the user's "Last_Activity" field the member's table. The problem is this would result in 500,000 MySQL Update queries all at once every 60 seconds.

Is there a better and simpler way to do this more efficiently? How do large websites do this? Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you really have that user base?

Comment: If you have 500,000 concurrent users, you really should have a decent distributed database in the first place to handle that workload; and a extra 500k updates per minute shouldn't be a major issue if you already have that in place

Comment: Nor would it be 500k updates "all at once".... they should be distributed over that 60 seconds, so only an average of 8,333 updates per second

Comment: Would the AJAX way described in my question above be the reasonable way to go for a large sites like this, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: code for what you actully have now, not you pipe dream

Comment: You should ask that question to your DevOps team, who is busy working a pretty sophisticated stack for that kind of trafic.

Comment: Ajax is a perfectly sensible approach to update the user record (make sure you're using a row-level locking engine like InnoDB rather than a table-level locking engine like MyISAM), though normal user activity would serve as well; but keep the counting as a periodic background process, storing the result in a fast cache system that you can then return to the users "on demand"

Comment: @Mark Baker - Thanks a lot for the advice, it is much appreciated. This is pretty much the plan I had, I'm the sole developer so I don't have anyone else to ask for advice. Basically I run the periodic background counting and store the total count in it's own tiny 1-row MySQL table once every 60 seconds so the count query doesn't need to be run on every page load (I assume this is what you meant by storing the total count number in a fast cache system?).

Comment: please provide a link to your site; it would be aspirational to see how 1 person created a site with a 100 million members

Comment: Rather than store it in the database, I'd be inclined to use a fast cache system like redis, which should be faster access than a database; and you can also cluster replicated redis servers behind a load balancer to distribute the workload provide a higher degree of performance with that many accesses.... if you have that many users, I'd be surprised if you aren't already using something like redis for sessions for your server farm, so take advantage of having it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to store the number of logged in users in a text file that your ajax request fetches, and then a once-per-minute cronjob can update this text file.

This will also reduce the overhead for your per-minute Ajax requests because they won't invoke PHP on the server (nor spawn another MySQL connection).

Comment: Thanks for the text-file advice! Something I never thought of for displaying the total users online count (I currently just stored this one number in a tiny 1-row MySQL general statistics table, although the text file idea would cut queries down!). The most difficult part for me is finding a way of keeping track minute by minute of who is online or not (AJAX updating "Last_Activity" time in the database every 60 seconds for each logged-in user, or some other method that may be more efficient?).

Comment: Text file really isn't a good solution unless you're running on a single server.... and you don't handle 500,000 concurrent users on a single server

Answer (score 1):

This is a vast number of users. You probably have at least 50 load-balanced web servers handling this traffic, and a large dedicated distributed data-handling system for dealing with current user sessions. As others have mentioned, bring this question to your operations team.

It's a big enough number of users that you can get away with considerable inaccuracy in your reporting of online users, and your users won't be the wiser.

If I were you and I still wanted to use MySQL for this I'd create an active-users table in each shard of the DBMS.  This table would have an indexed `session_expiration` timestamp. Each time I heard from each user I'd do this.

```
       UPDATE active 
          SET session_expiration = NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
        WHERE user_id = (the user you're hearing from);
```

If the user logs out explicitly, delete the `active` row. If they just walk away their sessions will expire five minutes out.

Once every five minutes or so, I'd use a [MySQL event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) to do these things.

```
       DELETE FROM active WHERE session_expiration <= NOW();
       UPDATE count SET active_count = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM active);
```

`count` is a one-row table.

Then, when you need to find the count of users online you query that table. If you want to give the illusion of dynamism, add or subtract a small random number from the value in the table.

The point is to take advantage of the fact that with half a million users, you don't have to be precisely accurate about the number online at any given minute. That's good, because stateless HTTP-based systems don't allow that precision.

Don't do the extra work involved with an AJAX post just to renew a user session, and certainly not once a minute. Make renewing the session a side effect of the user doing something interesting.

In the meantime, read about [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). It's a mistake to spend time working on scalability before you get the users. You're better off spending that time developing features that will attract those users.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice, I greatly appreciate it. I don't need the count to be perfectly accurate, 5 minutes will do just fine as you said. I'll probably combine your advice with Andreas above - maybe print the total count in a text file and use that instead of calling the 1-row count table. I currently use a 1-row table for other statistics on the site, but that new text file idea will help reduce the number of MySQL queries even more.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need an update query for 500k users. Your user's last activity field should change when user interacts with your website e.g. reloads a page, navigates to a new page, sends a message.